# Is it possible to read the content of a file from JavaScript in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to read the content of a file from JavaScript in the browser, such as using the HTML5 File API? All I could get is the meta data of a file, but not the content of the file.

Comment: There is an answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file